# How to adjust position of placeholder text of search bar

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the placeholder text of the search bar is a bit to the middle, how do move it to the left side?

The HTML code for this part is

```
<form class="navbar-form" action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
    <input class="search-icon" type="image" src="Assets/search.svg" alt="Submit" width="20px" height="20px">
</form>
```

```
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 60px;
}
```

^CSS

Comment: Add css code snippet as well

Comment: You need to show the relevent css code. It's probably because **1.** There are some `padding-left` on the `form` **2.** There are some `padding-left` or `margin-left` on the `input`. Just inspect the element and get rid of it.

Comment: Just include CSS code also. To me it feels padding-left is more but only from code can we tell whether this is reason indeed or not

Comment: Sorry! @HaoWu after reading your comment, i managed to fix the problem. It seems that I was applying padding on the left side also. oops

Comment: Yes, I figured it correct then. Check my answer because placeholder is within the input it cannot be margins :) Do accept and vote @YOUJIANGAN if my answer helps overall

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of padding within the input field. Try this:

```
input[type="text"]{
   padding-left:5px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** After you have updated your question. Below code will also work fine. But above CSS is a generic one.

```
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
```